# Can't add curve to the ZedGraph in C#

Tags: c#, zedgraph

I try to add multiple curves and yaxises using ZedGraph. But I added points to the first curve succesfully after I tried to add the second curve. The first one values' disappear and
`myCurve.Points.Count` equals 0. For example, if I add 6 curves, only the sixth one has values others count =0. Also any of them show up on the graph. Here is the code:

```
    colors = new Color[ff.documentColumnCount + 4];
    zedGraphControl1.IsShowPointValues = true;
    myPane = zedGraphControl1.GraphPane;
    LineItem myCurve;
    Color[] colors;
    myPane.XAxis.Type = ZedGraph.AxisType.Date;
    myPane.XAxis.Scale.Format = "HH:mm:ss";
    myPane.XAxis.Scale.MajorUnit = DateUnit.Second;

    zamanValue = new double[ff.tarihSaat.Length - 4]; // x axis time values. ff is another windows form name, no problem here.

    for (int i = 0; i < ff.tarihSaat.Length - 4; i++)
    {

        zamanValue[i] = (double)new XDate(ff.tarihSaat[i].Year,
                                          ff.tarihSaat[i].Month,
                                          ff.tarihSaat[i].Day,
                                          ff.tarihSaat[i].Hour,
                                          ff.tarihSaat[i].Minute,
                                          ff.tarihSaat[i].Second);
        counter++;
    }

    yaxisArray = new YAxis[ff.documentColumnCount + 4]; // temp y axises

    for (int k = 0; k < chckboxNumber; k++)
    {

        tempPointPairList.Clear();
        tempPointPairList = createPairPointList(k); // Creates points, I see the correct values everytime, also no problem here.

        minYvalues[k] = Findmin(tempPointPairList);
        maxYvalues[k] = FindMax(tempPointPairList);

        myCurve = myPane.AddCurve(ff.columnNames[k + 3], tempPointPairList, colors[k], SymbolType.None);
        myCurve.Line.Width = 2.5f;
        //myCurve.IsVisible = true;
        myCurve.YAxisIndex = k;
        myCurve.IsVisible = true;

        if (k == 0)
        {
            myPane.YAxis.IsVisible = true;
            myPane.YAxis.Scale.Max = 1;
            myPane.YAxis.Scale.Min = 0;
            myPane.YAxis.Scale.MajorStep = (myPane.YAxis.Scale.Max - myPane.YAxis.Scale.Min) / 10;
            myPane.YAxis.MajorGrid.IsVisible = true;
        }
        else
        {
            yaxisArray[k] = new YAxis(ff.columnNames[k + 3]);
            //yaxisArray[k].Color = colors[k];
            yaxisArray[k].IsVisible = false;
            yaxisArray[k].Title.IsVisible = false;
            myPane.YAxisList.Add(yaxisArray[k]);

            if (minYvalues[k] == maxYvalues[k])
            {
                yaxisArray[k].Scale.Min = minYvalues[k] - 0.1;
                yaxisArray[k].Scale.Max = maxYvalues[k] + 0.1;
            }
            else
            {
                yaxisArray[k].Scale.Min = minYvalues[k];
                yaxisArray[k].Scale.Max = maxYvalues[k];
            }

            myPane.YAxisList.Add(yaxisArray[k]);
        }
        yAxisListIndexes[k] = myPane.YAxisList.Count-1;

        minTextBoxes[k].Text = minYvalues[k].ToString();
        maxTextBoxes[k].Text = maxYvalues[k].ToString();

        durum[k].previousState = 1;
        durum[k].currentState = 1;
        chckBoxList[k].Checked = true;
        myCurve.Clear();

    }
    myPane.XAxis.Scale.Min = zamanValue[0];
    myPane.XAxis.Scale.Max = zamanValue[zamanValue.Length - 1];

    //myPane.YAxisList[0].IsVisible = true;
    zedGraphControl1.AxisChange();
    zedGraphControl1.Invalidate();
    zedGraphControl1.Refresh();
```

Where is the mistake?

Answer (score 2):

You don't add curves to each other, you add them to `myPane.CurveList` so you have them in myPane.CurveList[0], myPane.CurveList[1] and so on, not in myCurve. myCurve serves as store for current curve you are working with. When you call

```
myCurve = myPane.AddCurve(ff.columnNames[k + 3], tempPointPairList, colors[k], SymbolType.None);
```

a brand new curve is created, added to `myPane.CurveList` and is written into myCurve variable. It has a fresh state as it's just created. You can access your previous curve(s) in myPane.CurveList.

Comment: Thanks for answer but it didin't work. I add a code line like that : myPane.CurveList[k] = myCurve;
still,graphpane is empty

Comment: Also  myPane.CurveList[k] = myPane.AddCurve(ff.columnNames[k + 3], tempPointPairList, colors[k], SymbolType.None);
didn' add the points

Comment: Why did you add code like that? You asked why your myCurve.Points.Count = 0 when you add a new curve. I explained it to you. Also in your question you did not indicate that graph pane is empty, on the contrary, you wrote "Also any of them show up on the graph", which means that all the curves are shown. And finally I most likely failed to deliver my message to you clearly as I never suggested that you should write to CurveList array manually. All I said is that if it bothers you that myCurve.Points.Count is 0 you can retrieve all the previous curves (with non zero counts) from the CurveList.

Comment: I just replace the code line  myCurve = myPane.AddCurve(ff.columnNames[k + 3], tempPointPairList, colors[k], SymbolType.None); (old one) with myPane.CurveList[k] = myPane.AddCurve(ff.columnNames[k + 3], tempPointPairList, colors[k], SymbolType.None); (new one)
Sorry about my english, I should have said : Also none of them show up on the graph.
 But before and now, still don't access to the curve values. Yes, program adds them to the curve list but inside of them is empty. Point counts still equals to 0.